# Kendo UI Grid Time Datatype

Tags: sql, time, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to render a 'time' data type SQL column in kendo grid.

Can you tell me what should be the field type i should choose for 'time' column.

Currently I am using the 'string' data type and getting data as "PT10H41M39S".

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code 
inside the model field  `StartDate : { type : "date" }`

and inside the grid field

```
{ field: "StartDate", title: "Date", format : "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" }
```